# Elementary function with prescribed level sets

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I would like to find an elementary function of two variables such that the level set $f(x,y)=1$ is the ellipse with equation $2x^2+y^2=1$ and the level set $f(x,y)=2$ is the circle with equation $x^2+y^2=9.$

I have constructed non-elementary functions with those level sets in several ways, but I would like an elementary function to make it easier to give as an example.

Comment: Do you mind to show the "non-elementary" functions that you have found?

Comment: How did you know meromorphic solutions  existed ??

Comment: Robert Z: The easiest solution is probably to do interpolation on each half-line through the origin separately. Each half-line intersects both level curves, and between you interpolate in some nice way. (Say the value is zero at the origin.) Alternatively you can do $f(x,y) = g(2x^2+y^2)+h(x^2+y^2)$ where $g(1)=1$, g is increasing and $g(t)=1.5$ if $t\geq  2$, $h(9)=0.5$, $h$ is increasing and $h(t)=0$ if $t \leq 8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with a function $f$ of the form:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{ax^2+by^2}{cx^2+dy^2+e}$$
with real coefficients $a,b,c,d,e$ to be found. Then the level set $f(x,y)=k$ is given by
$$(a-kc)x^2+(b-kd)y^2=ke.$$
After a few calculations I got
$$f(x,y)=\frac{34x^2+16y^2}{16x^2+7y^2+9}.$$
Verify the shape of the level sets of $f$ via this [Desmos Demonstration](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ig9gcrx4wc).